# 400 http error while sending data via retrofit to flask server with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, flask, retrofit

I am trying to send longitude and latitude with autoincremented ID to my database running of Flask server via REST Api. I tested it with Postman and it worked fine. Here is example request body from postman.

```
{

"longitude":1.877771999,
"latitude":2.01999
}
```

The Flask code part is as follows:

```
class LocationValues(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'longitude',
        type=float,
        required=True,
        help="You must enter longitude"
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        'latitude',
        type=float,
        required=True,
        help="You must enter latitude"
    )

 def post(self):
        data = LocationValues.parser.parse_args()
        item = {'longitude': data['longitude'], 'latitude': data['latitude']}
        connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "INSERT INTO location VALUES(NULL ,?,?)"
        result=cursor.execute(query, (item['longitude'], item['latitude']))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        if result:
            return {"message":"Posted with success"},201

        return {"message":"failure"},400
```

I think the mistake is in the way I send the data to the server using retrofit. Here in my activity class i created my own test data which I try to send, without success.

```
val repository = Repository()
val viewModelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(repository)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
val buttonPost:Button = findViewById(R.id.button_post)
val myPostedData = Post2(Item2(5.2,9.99))
buttonPost.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.pushPost(myPostedJSON)
            viewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to send data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            })

        }
```

My Retrofit data class

```
data class Post2(
    val item: Item2
)

data class Item2(
    val longitude: Double,
    val latitude: Double
)
```

Repository

```
class Repository {
   
    suspend fun pushPost(post:Post2):Response<Post2>{
        return RetrofitInstance.api.pushPost(post)
    }
}
```

MainViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(private  val repository: Repository):ViewModel() {
    val myResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<Post>> = MutableLiveData()
    val myResponse2: MutableLiveData<Response<Post2>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun pushPost(post: Post2){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response : Response<Post2> = repository.pushPost(post)
            myResponse2.value = response
        }
    }
```

```
interface SimpleApi {

    @POST("adamapi")
    suspend fun pushPost(
        @Body post: Post2
    ): Response<Post2>

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Screenshot from Postman:
[image]

From the Flask side in debug mode while trying to send it with my phone, we see that it fails.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing wrong data in body of the API. You should pass the `Item2` as a body in the API request.

```
interface SimpleApi {

    @POST("adamapi")
    suspend fun pushPost(
        @Body body: Item2
    ): Response<Any>

}
```

To print header and body in logcat. Check [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses) article. This can help you to debug your api request and response easily.

Comment: It works. Why can't i pass my Post2? It has Item2 object in it..

Comment: @yras8 If you pass Post2 then it will create the wrong level of JSON object while parsing from a retrofit. And Your API doesn't fetch data properly from that. It will create  longitude, latitude inside of the item object.